# My code continuingly runs and I'm not sure why it gets stuck there on the matrix for my cluster analysis

Tags: r

```
tdm <- tm::DocumentTermMatrix(myCorpus)
tdm.tfidf <- tm::weightTfIdf(tdm)

tdm.tfidf <- tm::removeSparseTerms(tdm.tfidf, sparse= 0.999) 
tfidf.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm.tfidf) 

install.packages("proxy")
# Cosine distance matrix (useful for specific clustering algorithms) 
dist.matrix = proxy::dist(tfidf.matrix, method = "cosine"
```

My code gets stuck on the `tfidf.matrix <- as.matrix(tdm.tfidf)` line and crashes R. I'm not sure why

Comment: How large is your corpus? How much RAM do you have?

Comment: It says Large SimpleCorpus 35912 elements